# SQL вывести несуществующий запись

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, запрос

У меня есть 2 таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда сделать запрос `select * from tbNames, tbMarks where tbNames.ID = tbMarks.NO`, то информация об id=45 не выводится. Хочу вывести информацию о id=45 и в столбцах pr1, pr2 показать нули. Прошу простить если объяснил тяжело. Я использовал case, if но не смог это сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужен `LEFT JOIN`?

```
SELECT n.* , m.pr1, m.pr2
FROM tbNames n
LEFT JOIN tbMarks m
ON n.ID = m.NO
-- WHERE n.ID = 45
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Сработало!!!